# "if else" in python

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def love6(a, b):
    if a==6 or b==6 or a+b==6 or abs(a-b)==6:
        return True
    return False
```

I did only work on python one return statement, therefor I can understand use of "return True" but I can't understand use of "return False"?
Is this the correct way to use return statements by the standard programming in python? or is this shortcut way of using return to ignore some statement lines?

Comment: Downvoters, before the edits the code was indented with only one space, leading to "fast"'s confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, indentation controls in which block a statement goes in. In this case, "return False" is part of the `love6` function since it has only one group of 4 spaces and the return True is part of the if statement, since it has two groups of 4 spaces. Thus if the if statement condition is true, then the function will return True, otherwise the function will return False. The function could be more compactly written as:

```
def love6(a,b):
    return a==6 or b==6 or a+b==6 or abs(a-b)==6
```

Answer (score 7):

By default, python functions return `None` unless explicitly told to do otherwise via a `return` statement.

Apparently, the specification for the function is that it should return True if a is six, and False otherwise. Without the second return, the function will not return False, it will return None.

The second rule of the [Zen of Python (PEP 20)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is "explicit is better than implicit". This code adheres to that principle by explicitly returning either True or False, rather than depending on the implicit return of None.

Answer (score 6):

If the `if` statement does *not* match, the `return True` line is *not* executed and the code continues to the second `return` statement.

If the second return statement was not present, the function would just end and the default return value `None` would be returned instead.

The function can be simplified though; the expression used in the `if` statement *itself* is already evaluating to either `True` or `False`:

```
def love6(a, b):
    return a==6 or b==6 or a+b==6 or abs(a-b)==6
```

The `if` statement and two returns are entirely redundant here.

Comment: Just being a nitpicker here, but if `a` is an object whose `__eq__()` returns `5` for the input `6` (i. e. not a bool), what would the `love6` then return? ;-)

Comment: @Alfe: Sure, if `a` or `b` have custom `__eq__` hooks, then the assertion that the statement returns a boolean is not correct. But such custom behaviour is rare (usually employed by ORM libraries).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is basically the same as this:

```
def love6(a, b):
    if a==6 or b==6 or a+b==6 or abs(a-b)==6:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You need the last `return` because, without it, the function will return `None` if the if-statement's evaluation comes back `False`.  However, you do not need the `else` because of the fact that, as soon as Python hits a `return`, it exits the enclosing function.

Comment: Performance:  The `in` version needs to compute all four values and can then check if on of them is `6`.  The `or` version can short-circuit as soon as a match is found.  So the `or` is better from the performance point of view.  You _could_ use sth like `6 in (x() for x in (lambda: a, lambda: b, lambda: a+b, lambda: abs(a-b)))` but that's not shorter anymore ;-)

Comment: @Alfe - That's true.  That's why I said "this function is simple enough".  What this function does is very simple, so the time differences between the two is negligible.  But yes, with larger functions, using multiple `or`'s is a good practice.

Comment: Let's hope that `a` and `b` aren't instances of some number class way more complicated than `int` or `float` so that `a+b` takes half an hour ;-)

Comment: Alright @Alfe, you beat me.  For the sake of the fringe cases, I'll remove that part of my post :) (it wasn't vital anyways; more of an extra).

Answer (score 2):

If the `return False` wasn't there, then anytime the conditional wasn't true, the function wouldn't return anything. Or rather, it will return `None` because that's the default; that might accidentally work since `None` is falsy, but it's generally better to be explicit; code that uses an implicit `None` is usually a bug.

FWIW, if a function just returns the result of the conditional, you can just...return the result of the conditional:

```
return (a==6 or b==6 or a+b==6 or abs(a-b)==6)
```